obexpushd not found on Bookworm
In the past I have successfully received files via bluetooth on my Raspberry pi 4 running Bullseye by using obexpushd which I installed with apt-get. I was hoping to do the same with my new Raspberry Pi 5 running Bookworm, however apt-get tells me that the package is not found.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package obexpushd

Does anyone know what would be the best way to install it on Bookworm? Perhaps I'm missing a repository? Or perhaps is there a better OBEX server for receiving files via bluetooth on an RPI5?

Based on this, obexpushd is only in the unstable and testing branches, and was never in a recent previous stable version either. It's also been orphaned (has no real package maintainer) for almost a decade which may explain that (if there's no one running tests, it won't get out of "testing").
Possibly you previously had testing or unstable in your apt sources list for whatever reason, or your last install was quite old (it may have been in stable for wheezy and jessie).  To do that now, edit into /etc/apt/sources.list:
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian testing main contrib

Run sudo apt update, and you should be able to install. However, if you leave that, you may end up updating a lot of stuff from testing, so you probably want to remove/comment it out afterward and run sudo apt update again (which doesn't actually update/install anything other than the packages list).
If you can build stuff from source a better idea would be to do that:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/obexpushd/

I went back and looked at my source list om the RPI4 where I installed obexpushd with apt-get. In addition to it being commented out 'testing' is not listed. Additionally, installing from source looks dubious since it requires bluez_lib which is yet another package not found by apt. It looks like obexpushd for RPI5 is not viable.

Also quite old but maybe with more recent updates and available in RpiOS as obexftp: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/ObexFTP The Arch link because they generally have great docs; the official project page is here: http://dev.zuckschwerdt.org/openobex/wiki/ObexFtp

Yes, I use ObexFTP to push files to the receiving pc. However, I don't believe it can be used for receiving files via bluetooth. Thanks nonetheless for the suggestion. Back to the drawing board.

Update, Having some success with obex-bt.
